# I want to know how to do form validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to learn form validation and its not working.

```
// birthyear must be between 1900 and 2012. turn the birth year textbox color to yellow
        window.onload = function() {
        document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
        for(i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++){

       var x =
       document.forms[birthyear].value

    if (x != (>1900 &&<=2012)){
    alert("Must be between 1900 and 2012");
    x.this.style.color ="yellow";
    return false;
```

//this is how I have created the form:

```
<form action = "fake.php"></br>

    Username  
   <input class ="required"type = "text" name = "username" id ="username" /><br>
   Username
   <input class = "required"type = "text" name ="username"id ="username"/>   <br>


Birthyear
<input class  = "required" type = "number" name = "birthyear" id= "birthyear"/>

<input type = "submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `document.forms[birthyear].value` looks like your problem. Google how to loop through elements

Comment: Okay, so first off I want to point out that client side form validation is vulnerable. The user can disable Javascript. Could you post a jsfiddle or codepen with your full code? Have you checked the console? The code you've posted appears to have some syntax errors.

Comment: Please format the javascript snippet. You have no closing brackets and some lines are split up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(x<1900 || x> 2012){
    alert("invalid year");
```

Use if statement like this and try

and check the variable x , if it is taking the value user entered correctly.
Simply put alert for x variable and confirm it first

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement condition, `x != (>1900 &&<=2012)`, makes no sense. `>1900` and `<=2012` do not evaluate to booleans, so you can't use the `&&` operator on them. What you want is something like this:

```
x<1900 || x>2012
```

This checks if `x` is too low or too high, then uses the `||` (or) operator to check whether `x` is invalid in either way.

Comment: I am indeed using Javascript! and I am new to programming. One request to people who have the controls. I was bouted out of stack overflow for incorrectly indenting. I couldn't post my question in stackoverflow for 1 week. Can someone change this policy as young learners would be discouraged to continue programming.

Comment: @SQL75 Oh, wow, that's terrible. I'm not a mod and don't know how that works. You should post about that on [meta].

Comment: Another restriction is that you can't ask more than one question per day? If I had a PHD  in computer science or a professional software developer I won't be asking questions here.

Comment: @SQL75 I'm pretty sure that's a new user restriction, meaning that once you get 10 reputation, it's removed.

Comment: @SQL75 [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) is more information about new user restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax issues with your code.
If you want get value of the birthyear input. You don't have to iterate over elements in form (as you do using for loop), you can do so:
`document.forms[0].elements['birthyear']`

Also when you get a value of input element it type is string.
And before comparing it to a value with integer type, you should convert string to integer:

`intValue = parseInt(stringValue, 10);`

So you code will be following

```
<form action="fake.php">Username
    <input class="required" type="text" name="username" id="username" />Birthyear
    <input class="required" type="number" name="birthyear" id="birthyear" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
// birthyear must be between 1900 and 2012. turn the birth year textbox color to yellow
window.onload = function () {
    document.forms[0].onsubmit = function () {

        var birthYearElem = document.forms[0].elements['birthyear'],
            stringValue = birthYearElem.value,
            intValue = parseInt(stringValue, 10);

        if (intValue < 1900 || intValue > 2012) {
            alert("Must be between 1900 and 2012");
            birthYearElem.style.color = "yellow";
            return false;
        }
    }
}
<script>
```